# How can i skip execution with Gradle?

Tags: flyway

I'm using Flyway with Gradle and i need skip some migration files depending the database.

**Example:**

I have 3 migration files. All of then should be executed in the test database, but has one that shouldn't be executed in the production database.

**My question is:** Is it possible? If yes, how can i do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible. Use different values for flyway.locations based on the environment. Example: http://flywaydb.org/documentation/faq.html#db-specific-sql